# Want to add animated or gify image on my website background

Tags: css, animated-gif

I want to add animated or gify image(Doctor treating pateint) on my website background, can anyone please suggest me with some solution, its a single page website:  http://bighealth.co.in/

Comment: This isn't working for you? `<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/26ybx8Txk8lMfz7Ak/giphy.gif" />`

Comment: these are not high definition! need high definition animated or gif images, please suggest

Comment: You will never find a better quality than what @h3raldo provided, gif is limited with colors and resolution, better resolution and more frames mean bigger in file size and more slowness in browsing with a bad user experience. Low-quality video could be balance between the quality (as it will be better than gif) and the file size

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

1. change the url to the gif you want
2. change `background-size: cover;` to modify the way you want to display

```css
body{
    background-image: url('https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/dscovrepicmoontransitfull.gif');
    /* background-size: cover; */
}
```

Comment: these are not high definition! need high definition animated or gif images, please suggest

Comment: @IndradipPal are you here to ask for code or ask for high definition gif??? google the gif you want and replace it in the url

Answer (score 0):

If you want "high definition" animation, you need to add video as a background, if you mean this, then you need to provide the video in 3 types (.mp4, .ogg (or .ovg), webm), actually .mp4 could be enough, but will not work 100% in all brwosers, anyway here is the code:

```css
.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('../img/videoframe.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
  }

  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
        <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/video/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/video/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
            <source src="http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/video/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h1>Full screen HTML5 video background</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix te quidam commodo placerat. Mei ne dicunt minimum disputationi, purto everti adolescens id cum, quis veritus cotidieque eum ex. Ea eirmod atomorum posidonium sed, splendide dissentiunt an mel. Dolorem suavitate voluptatibus pro no. No duo conceptam cotidieque.</p>
        <p>Pro novum argumentum ad. Vix at inani civibus, congue veritus probatus ad vel. Eam ne quis omnesque euripidis, pri ea dicat etiam ponderum. At sit harum dolor persius, eos vocent adipisci ad, magna movet audiam pri no. Erant labores incorrupte id sit, constituto scripserit theophrastus quo no.</p>
        <p>Nam tacimates laboramus cu. Graeco tritani mel no. Iriure constituam mea te, quo integre salutatus ne. Case tota dicam te eam, quis minim assentior ei cum, sea eu verterem liberavisse. Modus officiis fabellas ea eos, in vis omittam ocurreret. Ea labitur assentior vix.</p>
        <p>Case tation integre sit an. Te cum mollis vocent similique, docendi volumus eu nam. Erant euismod partiendo nec ei. Vel malorum liberavisse cu. Fabulas efficiantur in duo.</p>
        <p>Ad qui brute fabulas rationibus, ex virtute omnesque vituperata vix. Ne case verterem probatus sit. In eam nulla tation debitis, has te alterum equidem definiebas. At summo facilisis eum. Vel ad nostro discere oportere, ad quod vitae officiis quo.</p>
        <p>Case tation integre sit an. Te cum mollis vocent similique, docendi volumus eu nam. Erant euismod partiendo nec ei. Vel malorum liberavisse cu. Fabulas efficiantur in duo.Ad qui brute fabulas rationibus, ex virtute omnesque vituperata vix. Ne case verterem probatus sit. In eam nulla tation debitis, has te alterum equidem definiebas. At summo facilisis eum. Vel ad nostro discere oportere, ad quod vitae officiis quo.</p>
    </div>
```

(click full page version to see the code running well, if run snippet not worked here, or visit the [original source here](http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/index.html))

The source of this code and more description provided here: https://slicejack.com/fullscreen-html5-video-background-css/